# Azure CPU metrics in percentage for web app monitoring using Metrics Explorer

Tags: azure

I am using the Azure Metrics Explorer and I would like to do the following:

Is it possible to output CPU Time in % rather than seconds?

I have looked everywhere in the app but unable to find a way of outputting as a percentage.
Am I missing something or does this not exist?
Any help appreciated

Thanks
Matthew

Comment: can you solve your issue as per this answer below?

Answer (score 0):

App Service metrics will give you statistics on the application (sites).
Metrics come standard with each resources. These cannot be modified. Link to official documentation [here][1].

App Service is deployed on a App Service **Plan** (serverfarms).
Cpu utilization, in percentage, is available. This is likely what you are looking for. Link to official documentation [here][1].

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d58985b2-e626-41a0-a54d-3f3f8f3a57ba/convert-azure-app-service-cpu-time-to-cpu-percentage?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

In azure portal, nav to `Diagnose and solve problems` -> click `Availability and Performance` -> then in the `CPU Usage`, you can see the percentage:

[image]